# Proving an operator is not trace class

Tags: operator-theory

Let $T$ denote the set of trace class operators and consider:

$$A = BC$$

If $B\notin T$ but $C\in T $ does it follow that $A\notin T$?

Edit: Where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are full rank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mathcal{H}$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, then the identity operator is not trace class, but any trace class operator multiplied by the identity is trivially a trace class operator.

Answer (score 2):

If $C=0$, then $A=BC=0$, hence $A \in T$.